# RPi4 Broken Resistor

Tags: pi-4, hardware

I have RPi4 8Gb, and accidentally, i broke a resistor on my Pi board and i want to replace it but i don't know the value of this resistor, so what is the value of this resistor i mentioned in picture below (thank you in advance):

[image]

Comment: I don't see any official documents pointing to this info. I appreciate your idea of fixing it, with the resister being so small. If it were me I would break it further and consider it officially broken.

Comment: My cheapy meter says it is 14Ω.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [RPi *conglomerate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) does not publish full schematics, or a parts list. Consequently, unless the part you are interested in is covered on their [partial schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html), you will have to measure the resistor value with an ohmmeter. The difficulty with this of course is two-fold:

1. The resistor must be removed from the circuit to get a dependable reading,
2. Your resistor is broken, and it *may* yield an incorrect value, even  after it's removed.

It's what the English might call a *sticky wicket*. No good answers for this sort of thing AFAIK. I've wondered if a [*co-operative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative) might be established whereby a skilled technician(s) removed parts, took measurements & cataloged them. OTOH, quite an effort for $30.

Answer (score 1):

What I would consider is purchasing another Pi, removing and measuring the value of that resistor. Then purchase new resistors and install one on each board. If you do not have the skill set to do the soldering you can hire it done, find somebody that is skilled enough to do this or you can just use the new board.

However you can simply measure the resistor on the new board without removing it and see what you get. Be sure to measure with the probes in both directions. Then use a standard value resistor closest to or next value higher than the highest value you measured. Install this on the old board and see if it works.